# How to use default csrf-token from AJAX request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm using Vuejs and I want to make an secure AJAX request (with axios) to my laravel server, but I think that CSRF protections doesn't work because I change the token of the frontend part and even then I can interact with the database.

I read that Laravel come with a file named [`bootstrap.js`] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-introduction) it is assumed that this file does this task by default, but it doesn't work for me. I think it's beacuse webpack doens't load the file when I run `npm run watch` but I don't know how to load it,

I searched for an answer but I only find Bootstrap tutorials :/

Comment: you are using laravel 5.8?

Comment: No, im using Laravel Framework 5.6.39

Answer (score 1):

In head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In ajax:

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the CSRF in the meta as _token. Like this:

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Visit the laravel documentation for this.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

And then access it in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should add VerifyCsrfToken middleware for the API group
(app/Http/Kernel.php)

Comment: Sounds logic let me see. But I need to include meta tag in my axios code ? Or it is automatic?

Comment: This declaration so your route will be wrapper middleware. So you need to include meta tag in the header of axios to passed